# A question in proof of Sylow 1st Theorem (from Hungerford Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am self studying algebra from textbook Thomas Hungerford and I was unable to understand a deduction in  proof of Sylow 1st Theorem on page 94

Its image:

[image]

> Question: How did in line 3 of proof, author deduced that
> $H$ is normal in $N_{G}(H) $?

I am not able to deduce that and shall be really thankful for help.

Comment: That's true by definition -- any subgroup is normal in its normalizer (which is what $N_{G}(H)$ is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subgroup $H\leq G$ is always normal in $N_G(H)$, this pretty much follows from the definition of the normalizer. $H$ is clearly a subgroup of $N_G(H)$, and for every element $g\in N_G(H)$ we have $gH=Hg$ by definition. And this means $H\trianglelefteq N_G(H)$.